# PHP execution path (parser)

Tags: php, compiler-construction

See the following snippet:

```
<?php
  die("----die----");

  sfafsadffas

  echo "foo";
  echo "bar";
?>
```

The result is:

```
Parse error: parse error in test.php on line 6.
```

Which is a bit unexpected, I would have thought we should get `----die----`.

Now see the following:

```
<?php
  die("----die----");

  echo "foo";
  echo "bar";

  sfafsadffas
?>
```

The result is:

```
----die----
```

What exactly is going on here?

Comment: In example 1 if you put a semicolon after `sfafsadffas;` it executes without any error.

Comment: HOW COME IT SHOWS `Parse error:`  FOR ME  ?

Answer (score 0):

The `echo` is indirectly effecting your program: besides printing to screen/browser the `echo` is doing `flush` to the output buffer which tries to print all the output that was "aggregated" so far. Since there's a syntax error before the `flush` it will be discovered at this point. You can reproduce the same error by doing:

```
<?php
die("----die----");

sfafsadffas
flush();
?>
```

But, if you'll flush the output buffer before the parser reaches the syntax error - the `die` will be executed.

```
<?php
die("----die----");

flush();
sfafsadffas
?>
```

will output `----die----` and then the parser will stop execution because it `died` and you won't reach the line that causes a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing PHP does when executing a file is to run a syntax check looking for obvious errors.  This includes missing `;` semicolons, mismatched braces `{}`, etc.

The first snippet fails this first test:

```
<?php
die("----die----");

sfafsadffas  // <-- no semicolon between this line of code and the next,
             //     so you get a 'parse error' before the file even gets run
echo "foo";
echo "bar";
?>
```

The second snippet survives the syntax check because of a little "feature" of PHP:  the parser counts `?>` as a semicolon.  So when you run:

```
<?php
die("----die----");

echo "foo";
echo "bar";

sfafsadffas
?>
```

The syntax check says "OK" and PHP proceeds to run the file.  And the file would in fact be perfectly valid if `sfafsadffas` was defined sometime earlier in the file.

And then because of your `die`, the code never gets down to line 7.

Answer (score -1):

The first fails, because the parser see's the invalid text and errors out.

The second may or may not fail depending on your PHP interpreter, it *may* not fail because the pre-processor (or parser) is ignoring extraneous data at the end of the file.

Answer (score -1):

the `sfafsadffas` is considered as a constant here.
In example 1, put a semicolon after `sfafsadffas` and you are using a constant a normal way so it works.
In example 2, You do no need to have a semicolon separate  last line of code see [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php)

Answer (score -2):

Throws Parse error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end on line 7
```

Please  check

http://writecodeonline.com/php/

Comment: His question is correct and your use of language is not welcomed at SO.

Answer (score -2):

**Example 1:**

It should not execute. Because the coding will run line by line. The invalid text will stop remain executions. Finally nothing will execute and execution will be fail.

**Example 2:**

By the reason of line by line execution the both echo statements will execute ,but finally the execution status will be fail.